# ReportViewer con valores nulos

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Genero un reporte con área, Tipo, y dos fechas dentro del cual el área y el tipo pueden contener o no valores,con los cuatro parámetros funciona correctamente, pero como puedo hacer que me ejecute la consulta correctamente cuando el valor es nulo? 
Gracias!

```
        //Array 
        ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[4];
        //Establecemos el valor de los parámetros
        parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("Area", lbl1.Text);
        parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("Source", lbl2.Text);
        parameters[2] = new ReportParameter("fecha1",f11);
        parameters[3] = new ReportParameter("fecha2", f22);
        //array al ReportViewer
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
       ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();'
```

Los parametros los extraigo de tres DropDownList
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: saludos Xavier, ¿y si agregas el código que tienes?

Comment: normal bro, estamos para servir :D

Comment: Código y algunas pantallas

Comment: en la última imagen se ve en blanco el valor de "Area" que por lo visto, es necesario.

Comment: Si, lo es, pero es un valor opcional para el usuario y si va como: null,"", Null o simplemente vacío me da error el reporte, no puedo hacer que se genere correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Al fin pude solucionarlo, al momento de declarar el DataSet, click derecho en DataTable, propiedades, revisar las propiedades de los datos y ahí se debe activar que acepte nulos, de lo contrario regresara error aunque sintaxis sea correcta y reporte acepte nulos, Saludos!